# Java static synchronized method handling many clients is mashing data

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a javaws app with a chunk of code running on the server side. Here is a simple example:

```
public class Stuff {

    public static synchronized coolStuff(String something, String somethingElse)
    {
        System.out.println("It is a: " + something);
        System.out.println("It is also a: " + somethingElse);
    }
}
```

I have multpiple clients (400+) calling this piece of code via a controller, ultimatly the following is sent to the server side:

```
Clinet 1: coolStuff("BIG TRUCK", "BIG CAR");
Client 2: coolStuff("BIG TV", "BIG PHONE");
```

The serverside will printout (log) a mix of both request, something like:

```
It is a: "BIG TV"
It is also a "BIG_CAR"
```

I'm not sure how this is happening since my server method is synchronized. Keep in mind, this is just a random code example. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Are there multiple JVM instances involved? `synchronized` can make only guarantees within it's own.

Comment: @Sotirios Sorry, I deleted my previous code involontary. So yes, a `synchronized` block is present, so I checked for the spec if some weird case could occur regarding multiple `println`, although logically no. Surely, the blending comes from the initial caller of the method, maybe not thread-safe itself, conflicting with the expected output.

Comment: Just because System.out.println is synchronized within the java code does not guarantee that the host platform you're passing the text to makes any guarantee about the actual console buffer preserving order.  Content is only guaranteed to be passed from JVM to the host system in a particular order, then java loses control.  This is particularly obvious when you run inside of an IDE that traps and redirects system console out.  Spawn a few hundred threads and attempt to write to it in a sane synchronized way and you will get garbage.

Comment: @zapl yes, there are a few server instances running on the same tomcat instance on the same server. So the only difference between them is the webapp name (mywebapp1, mywebapp2, etc). I've thought if it would be possible if two webapps running under that same JVM can cause the mix up but I doubt that as it would be major issue if my app can hose another app like that.

Comment: You'd probably get the desired sequence if you did `System.out.flush();` at the end of your synchronized block.

Comment: @Hot Licks - thanks for the tip, but this is just an example. In the real world I don't print the lines, I use the info to query a db. log4j logs the db queries and i'm getting parameters mixed in the queries. I've also starting logging the parameters on each request and seeing the mix aswell. It doesn't happen on every transaction but it appears to be some sort of race condition somewhere.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible if you have properly synchronized the code.  I'd rather suspect that your code are not properly synchronized which caused the issue. e.g. logging code is somewhere not synchronized, or you are synchronizing a instance method instead, and there are multiple instance etc

Comment: If you are sure that you have the static method synchronized, and the logging are only happening in that static method, and you are sure that there is only 1 JVM, then one possibility is, there may be more than 1 classloader loading your class containing that static method (can be caused by multiple web app, or during hot redeploy, etc).  In such case, there are more than one copy of that class in the memory, causing synchronization not working as expected.

Comment: Note that if you have two different classes that have synchronized methods they will not be synchronized relative to each other.  A synchronized static method, by default, is synchronized on the Class object.  (And this is the root of the problem discussed by Arian directly above.  That sort of scenario is unlikely in "normal" code but fairly likely in servers.)